# How do I get rid of the package e1071 installation error?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, e1071

I am trying to run the confusionMatrix function but it shows this error and when I try to install the package it shows the error in bold below it.

Error: package e1071 is required
Traceback:

1. confusionMatrix(factor(test_data$area, levels = 1:100), factor(test_data$pred_rf,
   .     levels = 1:100))
2. confusionMatrix.default(factor(test_data$area, levels = 1:100),
   .     factor(test_data$pred_rf, levels = 1:100))
3. getFromNamespace("confusionMatrix.table", "caret")(classTable,
   .     positive, prevalence = prevalence, mode = mode)
4. requireNamespaceQuietStop("e1071")
5. stop(paste("package", package, "is required"), call. = FALSE)

---

**also installing the dependency ‘proxy’
Warning message in install.packages("e1071"):
“installation of package ‘proxy’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("e1071"):
“installation of package ‘e1071’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done**

---

How do I solve this?

Comment: What happens if you restart R Studio then try and install it again?

Comment: The first error message tells us that 'e1071' library was missing. 
When you tried to install 'e1071', the error message tell us that e1071 failed to install, and the reason might come from a failure to install the "proxy" library.  So, you could try to install "proxy" first. Then, re-install "e1071"

Comment: You can let R's package handling help by using `install.packages('pkg_you_want', dependencies = TRUE)`, which coordinates having all other packages that pkg_you_want needs to operate, installed. This can still fail, as friends of friends have other friends, which means dependencies = TRUE only accounts for the first level of pkgs dependencies and not their further dependencies. At which point you're installing step by step as suggested above.